# Matlab/Octave: how to display a matrix while specifying grid line spacing?

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave

I would like to display a 2D array named `C` under MATLAB/Octave; I would normally use `imagesc`, but this time I would like to specify multiple cell sizes.

`imagesc` does not allow me to do this: if I set `x` and `y` as two elements vectors, `imagesc(x,y,C)` simply specifies the image location, but does not give me control over the grid spacing.

I was thinking of using `pcolor`, but it creates a pseudocolor plot using each set of four adjacent points in C to define a surface rectangle. Therefore a 4x4 matrix will appear as a 3x3 grid!

**QUESTION:**
do you know about any built-in function that would allow me to display a 2D array while specifying grid lines spacing?

Thanks a lot for your answer!

**EXAMPLE**

Here is an example of what I would like to achieve.
Let's say I want to display the matrix `C=magic(4)`

`imagesc(C)` will return:

[image: Image returned by imagesc(C)]

Now let's define two arrays `X` and `Y` containing the pixel's width and height (or length):

```
X=[1, 1, 2, 1]
Y=[1, 1, 1, 1]
```

I am looking for a function of `X`, `Y` and `C` that would return the following image:

[image: Image of the representation I am trying to achieve]

**Please note that I created the image above using paint!**

Comment: have a look at the implementation of `pcolor`. It uses `surface` with `z = zeros(..)` and sets a fixed view. Using surface seems to be a good way for your problem

Comment: Hi Andy! Thanks for your quick reply. I just tried using `surface` with `z=zeros(...)` as you suggested but unfortunately the result is similar to what I get with `pcolor`: a 4x4 matrix appears as a 3x3 checkboard plot!

Comment: can you give a code example of the problem? It works for me, `imagesc (magic (4))` draws a 4x4 checkboard plot.

Comment: @Sheldon it's not clear to me what you're asking. What do you mean by "multiple cell sizes" or by "grid spacing"?. Are you asking e.g. if there's a way to control the aspect ratio of the individual pixels in an `imagesc`-generated image? Are you asking if you can have pixels of varying size in the same image?

Comment: @carandraug: Thanks for your comment. I will provide a code example in my post.

Comment: @Tasos: Sorry for not being clear enough! Indeed, I would like to control the aspect (length and width) of each of the individual pixels in an `imagesc` generated image. I will provide an example in my post.

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarifying. The reason I asked this is because visible aspect ratio has nothing to do with the data per se, but more to do with the presentation, i.e. axis x/y scaling and axes size. I will work on a couple of examples to demonstrate this for you.

Comment: @Sheldon: why don't you just duplicate the columns/rows? How do you expect the axis labels? Excactly as in your example (3 and 4)?

Comment: @Andy: the example I provided here is overly simple: I am actually dealing with substantially larger matrices (e.g. 100x100) and a large variety of cell sizes (e.g. some cells may appear 500 times larger than others). Your duplicate approach seems interesting, but I wonder how efficient it will be memorywise: for example, it implies representing a single-valued cell of "size" 500x500 by a 500x500 matrix... As for the axis labels, I am open to any suggestion :-)

Comment: Sounds like what actually want to do is interpolate your data. Look into the `interp2` function (or the `imresize` function in the image package), and plot the interpolated data.

Comment: @carandraug: Thank you for your suggestion, but I am not trying to interpolate my data array. The answer provided by Andras solves my problem with `pcolor`.

Comment: @Sheldon note my comment under Andras' answer. **pcolor interpolates values between the vertices**. Make sure this is compatible with what you want because it's not *exactly* what you want.

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer: this solution is simple, and close to the intended result, but it will distort the data due to the way `pcolor` creates the plot. For a more cumbersome but precise solution, see [the answer by Tasos Papastylianou](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39261349/5067311).**

You could kludge your way with `pcolor`, you just have to use `cumsum` to turn your pixel widths into coordinates. The kludgy bit is adding zero-padding that is later thrown away by `pcolor`:

```
C = magic(4);
X = [1, 1, 2, 1];
Y = [1, 1, 1, 1];
Xt = [0, cumsum(X)];
Yt = [0, cumsum(Y)];
Ct = C;
Ct(end+1,end+1) = 0; % or more nicely: pre-allocate and overwrite with C

pcolor(Xt,Yt,Ct);
%optionally flip y axis to reconstruct imagesc() output
axis ij;
```

[image: output]

Comment: many thanks for your answer, Andras! It definitely solves my problem!

Comment: btw, note that the colours / values you get using this method are *not* the same as your matrix or those that you'd get using imagesc. Although visually it should look close enough if that's all you're interested in.

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou thanks, I'm indeed a bit wary about the zero-padding. What would be best if we could give `imagesc` custom coordinates, but I see why this is not an option for plotting images. Anyway, visual data representation like this should be only as precise as this method itself:)

Comment: btw, try `shading interp` for instant groove-on :D

Comment: @AndrasDeak I have an *area*-based solution which builds on your answer. Rather than add a separate answer, may I edit yours to include it as an alternative?

Comment: ach, on second thought I'll add it as a separate answer rather than litter yours :p

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr**: control aspect ratio with daspect and draw custom gridlines

---

**Explanation**: Find below several examples which will give you an understanding of what's going on.

Here is the solution I mentioned in the comments. It involves drawing an image with `imagesc` and coordinates, as you hinted, and also controlling the pixel aspect ratio using `daspect`. For complete control, it's best to draw your gridlines separately.

Run each cell separately to see what it does.

```
%%%% In file LookAtMeHacker.m
[Shodan,M] = imread('http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/shodan/images/0/09/SHODAN_1.jpg');

%% Aspect ratios for normal imagesc
% Default aspect ratio, automatically calculated from image size
imagesc(Shodan); 
ImageSize   = size(Shodan)
AspectRatio = daspect()
title(sprintf('Default view. Aspect Ratio= %d:%d', ...
              AspectRatio(2), AspectRatio(1)));
%% Isotropic pixels
axis equal; AspectRatio = daspect();
title(sprintf('Axis ''equal''. Aspect Radio= %d:%d', ...
              AspectRatio(2), AspectRatio(1)));

%% Custom aspect ratio: 16:9
daspect([9,16,1]); AspectRatio = daspect();
title(sprintf('Custom Aspect Radio= %d:%d', ...
              AspectRatio(2), AspectRatio(1)));

%% Aspect ratios for imagesc with coordinates
% Default view
imagesc([0,40], [10, 30], Shodan)
AspectRatio = daspect()
title(sprintf('Default view.with coordinates; Aspect Ratio= %d:%d', ...
              AspectRatio(2), AspectRatio(1)));

%% Isotropic pixels IN TERMS OF COORDINATES
axis equal; AspectRatio = daspect();
title(sprintf('Axis ''equal''. Aspect Radio= %d:%d', ...
              AspectRatio(2), AspectRatio(1)));

%% Custom VISUAL aspect ratio: 16:9
daspect([9/20,16/40,1]); AspectRatio = daspect();
title('Custom Aspect Radio= 16:9')

%% Custom gridlines:
for i = 10:5:30; line(xlim, i, 'linestyle',':','color','w', 'linewidth',3); end;
for i = 0:5:40; line(i, ylim, 'linestyle',':','color','w', 'linewidth',3); end;
```

End result:

[image]

Comment: Ah. Apologies. I answered the version of the question that was still talking about gridlines and "aspect ratios". Clearly the edited question asks for something different now :p   Oh well. I'll leave this here in case somebody else bumps into this question looking for actual aspect ratios / grid line spacings etc.

Comment: Many thanks for your nicely conceived tutorial, Tasos! It does not really answer my question, but your examples will definitely will come in handy on future projects. Awesome _System Shock_ reference, by the way! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This adds on Andras' nice `cumsum` approach; however, the problem with `pcolor` is that the values you get in the *faces* are not the values / colours you expect in your matrix, but *interpolations* from the values applied at the *vertices* of the `pcolor` graph.

Here's an approach that works around this. It's slow, because we're essentially plotting an area for each patch, and manually assigning colour, but you'll get the idea.

```
C = magic(4);
X = [1, 1, 2, 1];
Y = [1, 1, 1, 1];
Xt = [0, cumsum(X)];
Yt = [0, cumsum(Y)];

Ct = round(1 + (255 * mat2gray(C))); % convert to 256 colourmap indices
Cmap = permute(jet(256),[1,3,2]);
Ct = Cmap(Ct,1,:);
Ct = reshape(Ct, size(C,1), size(C,2), []);

LimX = Xt(end);
for i = size(C,1):-1:1
  for j = 1:size(C,2);
    area([Xt(j),LimX],[Yt(i+1),Yt(i+1)], 'edgecolor','none','facecolor', squeeze(Ct(i,j,:))); hold on;
  end
end
hold off;
axis ij; daspect([1,1,1]);
```

Result / Comparisons:

[image]

Comment: Interesting comparison! I have to admit both solutions look so close that I got confused at first! I will stick to Andras' script when trying to visually inspect my array, but will use yours if I ever need to display the "true" values.

Comment: I agree this should be a separate answer, "simple" vs "good" are nicely separated now;) Nice job! I added a disclaimer to my post to direct interested parties here.